# How to drag tabs which are custom components in JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have simple JPanel that serves as tabComponent of JTabbedPane. It is MainTabComponent class:

```
public class MainTabComponent extends JPanel {

    private JLabel label;

    public MainTabComponent(String title, MainTabbedPane mainTabbedPane) {
        // unset default FlowLayout gaps
        super(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 0));

        setOpaque(false);

        label = new JLabel(title, Images.tabIconSaved, JLabel.LEADING);

        add(label);
        // add more space between the label and the button
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 5));
        // tab button
        JButton button = new TabButton();
        add(button);
        // add more space to the top of the component
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 0, 0, 0));
       }
}
```

Next I need to allow user to drag tabs(that is MainTabComponent).

The problem is that method tabForCoordinate of TabbedPaneUI doesn't return correct tab index.
It returns always 0.

So I need to find out tab index on mouse click, but how to do this with custom tab?

Thank you!

Comment: `The problem is that method tabForCoordinate of TabbedPaneUI doesn't return correct tab index.` This method is abstract and its class is abstract. You can `find out tab index on mouse click` with `getSelectedIndex()` of `JTabbedPane`.

Comment: And how to find index of tab on mouseEntered event?

Comment: Add a `MouseAdapter` and call `getSelectedIndex` from inside `mouseEntered`.